# Garbage collector of singleton with daemon thread

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection, singleton, daemon

I've implemented a logger as a singleton, where all messages go into a queue, and a daemon thread collects those messages from the queue, and prints them.
The reason I used a daemon thread is so I don't have to explicitly close the logger once I'm done with it (or the application exits).
I expected that once the logger is deleted (by the garbage collector) when the application closes, then the `__del__` method would run and cleanup after. I was surprised that wasn't the case.

When I changed the thread to be non-daemon, it worked just fine (obviously I had to make some other changes so that the application would exit). I wonder if there's something I'm doing wrong, or that's just a bad practice overall.

Attached here is the code: (I would suggest that everything after the `__del__` function is not interesting).

```
import os
import sys
import time
import Queue
import weakref
import datetime
import threading

class Logger(object):
    """
    Logger class implemented with a queue of messages, and supports only a single instace.
    This instance can be acquired by using the "GetLogger" method.
    """

    __instance = None

    @classmethod
    def GetLogger(cls, fpath, source_name=None):

        if cls.__instance is None:

            return Logger(fpath, source_name=source_name)

        else:
          if source_name is None:
              cls.__instance().log('%s@%s: %s\n' % (cls.current_date(), cls.current_time(), "Using existing Logger instance"), "REUSAGE")
          else:
              cls.__instance().log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (cls.current_date(), cls.current_time(), source_name, "Using existing Logger instance"), "REUSAGE")

        return cls.__instance()

    def __init__(self, fpath, start_time = time.time(), source_name=None):

        if self.__instance is not None:

            raise ValueError("Singleton object already exists")

        self.__instance = weakref.ref(self)
        self.__start_time = start_time
        self.__queue = Queue.Queue()
        self.__listener = threading.Thread(target=self._listen)
        self.__listener.daemon = True
        self.__listener.start()
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(fpath)):
            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fpath))
        self.__f = open(fpath, 'a')
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), "Created a new Logger instance"), "CREATION")
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, "Created a new Logger instance"), "CREATION")

    @staticmethod
    def current_date():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now().date().isoformat())

    @staticmethod
    def current_time():
        return str(datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat())

    def _listen(self):

        while True:

            msg = self.__queue.get()
            if msg is None:
                break

            self.__print_message(msg)

    def __print_message(self, msg_tup): # msg_tup = (message, level, stdout)
        msg_time = time.time()
        if msg_tup[2]:
            try:
                print(("|%013.6f|%-8s>>>%s" % (msg_time - self.__start_time, msg_tup[1], msg_tup[0]))),
                sys.stdout.flush()
            except:
                pass
        try:
            self.__f.write("|%013.6f|%-8s>>>%s" % (msg_time - self.__start_time, msg_tup[1], msg_tup[0]))
            self.__f.flush()
        except:
            pass

    def log(self, msg, level, to_stdout=True):
        self.__queue.put((msg, level, to_stdout))

    def close(self):
        self.__queue.put(None)
        self.__instance = None

    def __del__(self):

        while not self.__queue.empty():
            msg = self.__queue.get()
            if msg is not None:
                self.__print_message(msg)
        print("Dead...")
        self.__f.close()
        self.close()

    def info(self, msg, source_name=None, to_stdout=True):
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), msg), "INFO", to_stdout=to_stdout)
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, msg), "INFO", to_stdout=to_stdout)

    def debug(self, msg, source_name=None, to_stdout=True):
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' %
                               (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), msg), "DEBUG", to_stdout=to_stdout)
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, msg), "DEBUG", to_stdout=to_stdout)

    def trace(self, msg, sdource_name=None, to_stdout=True):
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' %
                               (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), msg), "TRACE", to_stdout=to_stdout)
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, msg), "TRACE", to_stdout=to_stdout)

    def warn(self, msg, source_name=None, to_stdout=True):
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' %
                               (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), msg), "WARN", to_stdout=to_stdout)
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, msg), "WARN", to_stdout=to_stdout)

    def error(self, msg, source_name=None, to_stdout=True):
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' %
                               (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), msg), "ERROR", to_stdout=to_stdout)
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, msg), "ERROR", to_stdout=to_stdout)

    def critical(self, msg, source_name=None, to_stdout=True):
        if source_name is None:
            self.log('%s@%s: %s\n' %
                               (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), msg), "CRITICAL", to_stdout=to_stdout)
        else:
            self.log('%s@%s - %-17s: %s\n' % (self.current_date(), self.current_time(), source_name, msg), "CRITICAL", to_stdout=to_stdout)
```

Comment: What is your reason for expecting the GC to reclaim your `Logger` instance before the program terminates? A daemon thread should continue running right up until the very end, and the thread's main routine, `_listen()` always has a live reference to the object through its `self` argument.

Comment: Basically my claim is that garbage collector deletes object even after program comes to an end. For example:
`class X(object):

  def __init__(self):

    print "Created..."

  def __del__(self):

    print "Destroyed..."

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = X()`
It might be wrong, but if so, why is that wrong to assume that daemon threads are garbage collected when they're done? Is there another way of implementing a logger which outputs on a different thread, and not having to worry about closing it?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "after program comes to an end." I am not surprised that your `class X` instance gets deleted when the main thread in the example above runs off the end of the script. But that's a different case from a daemon thread that's running a `while True:...` loop. The `class X` object was freed because the main thread left the scope of the variable, `x`. But when will the daemon thread in your original question ever leave the scope of the `self` argument in your `__listen(self)` method? I would expect the process to be terminated before that could ever happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GC will never reclaim your `Logger` instance so long as any "live" variable in the program still contains a reference to it. The `self` argument of the `listen(self):...` method is one such variable, and that's the top-level method in which the daemon thread is running.

```
def _listen(self):
    while True:
        msg = self.__queue.get()
        if msg is None:
            break
        self.__print_message(msg)
```

The GC can not reclaim the `Logger` instance until the daemon thread returns from `_listen()`. There's only one way for that to happen:

```
def close(self):
    self.__queue.put(None)
```

If you "close" your logger, then the daemon thread eventually will get `None` from the queue, it will return from the `_listen()` call, and the daemon thread will end. But, you said

> The reason I used a daemon thread is so I don't have to explicitly close the logger.

If you don't close the logger, then the daemon thread will never end, the `self` arg in `_listen(self)` will never go out of scope, and the `Logger` instance will never be reclaimed.

Comment: I believe this answers my question. Do you know of any other way where a logger won't need to be closed explicitly (without using daemon threads)? Preferably with separate thread for IO.

Comment: You said, "...when the application closes..." in your original question. I don't know enough about your application to know what all reasons there are for the application to "close" or how it "closes." If it's possible for some other process to explicitly kill your application (e.g., with a `kill -KILL` signal in a unix-like OS) then there's no way for any process to "handle" that in any language. For any other kind of shutdown,... Sorry, but I'm not really a Python guru: I don't know the "pythonic" way to do a lot of things.